# Can't Boot From Hard Drive Turned External Drive

Tags: hard-drive, boot, partitioning, ssd

I had been dual-booting Windows 8 and Ubuntu. I recently got an SSD, so I removed the HDD and made it an external drive. I am unable to boot from the now-external hard drive, and I'm not sure why. Windows Disk Management doesn't indicate that any partition is active, nor will it let me make one so. Trying from the command line returns the error that the "active" command can only be used on a fixed MBR disk. According to the KDE Partition Manager, the EFI System Partition is flagged boot.

As you can probably tell from this question, I'm a complete noob. I hope I'm not wasting your time with a ridiculously simple question, but I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest cloning your current hard drive to the ssd if possible.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. What I would really like to do, though, is have an external drive that is bootable. My new system is set up the way I like it; it's not a matter of transferring data/settings. Isn't there some way I could have a second, portable operating system in the form of this external drive?

Answer (score 0):

In the Drive Bios make the internal drive the second drive option so that when you unplug the external 1st option to boot drive the secondary drive will boot instead in the external drives absence.